# JQuery partial postback for dynamic control doesn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dynamic-controls, partial-postback

I am using [Eric Hynds’ jQuery](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) for a multi-select list. I have created the control dynamically in the code behind and can successfully bind to it.

The source would look something like:

```
<div class="multiselectlist">
  <select id="MainContent_List" multiple="multiple" name="ctl00$MainContent$List">
</div>
```

The dynamic controls are in an update panel. When I hit a button it does a partial postback and it loses the jQuery features associated with it.

I assumed that I would need to “re-register the script” so I did this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this, GetType(), "multiselect", Page.ResolveClientUrl("../../Assets/Scripts/jquery.multiselect.min.js"));
```

Unfortunately nothing happens. I’m fairly sure that it is the javascript that isn’t run. Am I not registering the javascript correctly?

Comment: Look at the def tools in your browser. In FF and Chrome, you can see which scripts are loaded. Also, why not just link the script in the mark-up? Is it conditionally loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct you just need to re-bind the JQuery Multiselect to the `select` control.

This is because the content of an `UpdatePanel` is re-rendered every time a partial post occurs, this means that the DOM elements are removed and re-created on every post

In order to accomplish your goal just re-bind the events as follows:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function (a, e) {
     // place here the re-initialization of your multiselect plugin
});
```

Additionally, you could use the `shortcut` to the function:

```
function pageLoad() {
    // place here the re-initialization of your multiselect plugin
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm having difficulty putting up code here properly.

    string multiSelectScript = "$(function () {Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);" + "function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {" + "$(\"#MainContent_ClaimantType_ID_MultiSelectList\").multiselect({selectedList:4}); } });";

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "multiselect", multiSelectScript, true);

And nothing happens.
Is the problem here that I'm registering the page in the register startup script and not the exact control?
Thanks.

Comment: Actually your suggestion did work.  I was running it in FireFox so I could see the javascript added to the page source using FireBug. And nothing was happening.  
I just tried it in IE and it does work there. 
So the next challenge is to get it working in FireFox.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinitialize the multi-select list as below

```
$.ajaxStop(function(){
    $("#MainContent_List").multiselect();
});
```

Comment: Good answer, although note: As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStop() method should only be attached to document. $( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
  $( "#loading" ).hide();
});